# Get Property value and display to people search result

Tags: 2013, people-search

This is for SharePoint 2013.

I'm new in this domain.

I have to realise an intranet with SharePoint 2013. I want to display a property in people search results.

I followed this [post](http://antclegg.blogspot.de/2013/09/people-search-with-work-number-in.html), it works well, I display the "location".

But the problem is that it displays the value that is in "Central Administration --> Manage User Profiles".

And I want to display the value that is in "Edit Profile" when you click on the name of someone (when you use the search for poeple e.g) and you go in his "Edit Profile".

ps : sorry for my bad english.

EDIT :

This is the value in ProfAdminEdit.aspx (Central Administration --> Manage User Profiles).
I display "C2" but I want the other value.

[image]

This is the value in EditProfile.aspx (in search navigation, I search e.g Lee and when I click on his name, I arrive on his personal site and there, I can "edit" his profil, I want the value that is here and not the value "C2")

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a value from the User Profile in Search Results you have to create and map a Managed Property for the User Profile Property. Once you do that you can create a display template that will display the value in your search results.

I have written a complete walk through with examples of this process here: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/

EDIT
It appears that your Managed Metadata Service and browser language settings are not configured correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I haven't problem to display my managed property (here "location"). The problem is that it displays the value that is in "Central Administration --> Manage User Profiles" and I want to display the value that is in "Edit Profile" when you click on the name of someone (when you use the search navigation for people e.g) and you go in his "Edit Profile", on the personal site of someone. I have different values. Do you understand?

Comment: I don't understand. They should be the same value. Can you edit your question and add a couple screen shots?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: If you look at the Term Set and the Term "C2" in English, is the French translation the value you are seeing in your second image? Can you chance the UI language to English to test?

Comment: Ok, when I change UI langage to English, I see "C2" instead of "Batiment...". But, now I change the langage settings of my siteCollection (Site Settings -->  Language settings --> I checked French). The search center is in French but when I search people, I have always "C2". How to achieve this?

Comment: You have to configure the Managed Metadata Service for default language of France (I believe) I am not an MMS expert.